# How does Miro fly to Trondheim without destroying all the ecosystem of the planet with Descolada?

Tags: character-motivation, enders-game

I have only read *Ender's Game* and the *Speaker for the Dead*, and did not yet read the other books from the series. So it might be already explained in other books. But I could not find the explanation from the Speaker for the Dead.

It is explained in the book, that the Descolada is reason the Starways Congress could not evacuate the Lusitania Colony. The Xenobiologists say that if anyone from Lusitania goes to another planet, the Descolada agent would destroy all the ecosystem, and they would not have the time to make all the animals and plants resistant to the disease.

But, in the last chapter, Miro decides go to Trondheim, aboard Ender's starship, and take the trial. Why would Miro do that? And why would Ender agree with this?

Comment: In the Ender's series does the author ever answer the question whether or not the Descolota is bad or good, or is the subject continued in another book by the author?

Comment: If you have a question of your own, use the [ask question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link instead of adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**He didn't actually end up on Trondheim.**

Instead he intercepts Valentine halfway there and then returns.  Ender sent him as a sort of time machine, due to the near-light speed time dilation effect (when discussing the idea when he had it, Olhando explicitly mentioned remembering Mazer Rahkam's story).

This was wanted both by Miro himself; AND by Miro's family which was not handling his change in health well, Ender figured the family would handle it better if they had some time, and grew up a bit.

Comment: Might be worth putting this answer in a spoiler even though the books have been out for decades.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits